# TypeScript: Convert literal string type definition to string value (like typeof operator), or vica versa?

Tags: string, typescript, types, constants

I want to access the string value of a string literal type, similar to typeof operator in C#, otherwise I must define it twice...

```
myStringLiteral: 'STRING TYPE';

myString:string = typeof(myStringLiteral); // Want myString = 'STRING TYPE'...
```

Or, if the opposite is possible:

```
const myString:string =  'STRING TYPE';

myStringLiteral: myString;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to not use an explicit type annotation to let the compiler infer the string literal type for the constant (or manually specify the string literal type not `string`).

If you have the `myString` constant typed correctly, you can just use `typeof` to get the type of the constant in a type annotation or type definitions:

```
const myString = 'STRING TYPE'; // typed as 'STRING TYPE'

type myStringLiteral = typeof myString; // myStringLiteral is 'STRING TYPE'

let otherVar: typeof myString;
```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed you can still use string literal value type on your const string though (but this is opposite of what I want to do anyway.)